# как сделать чтобы картинка наследовала цвет заднего фона

Tags: html, css

есть фон  такой из личного  блога Билла Гейтса [image: оранжевый] там как видите 2 фотки они приняли цвет заднего фона оранжевый(на одном он с женой в другом какой то чертёж).Как добится такого результата вот уже 3 дня не могу найти ответ.Вот ссылка на сайт если кому понадобится

https://www.gatesnotes.com/globalpages/bio

Comment: Это просто png с прозрачностью. Никаких примудростей

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё же банально просто. Фото с прозрачным фоном является `background-image` элемента `div`, который, в свою очередь, является дочерним по отношению к другому `div` с `background-color`

```css
#test {
  background-color: #fdbd12;
  height: 527px;
}

#bill {
  background-image: url(https://www.gatesnotes.com/tgn/bio/img/sprite.png);
  background-position: -303px 0;
  width: 433px;
  height: 531px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 171px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="bill"></div>
</div>
```

Оно же, но без фона

```css
#test {
  /*background-color: #fdbd12;*/
  height: 527px;
}

#bill {
  background-image: url(https://www.gatesnotes.com/tgn/bio/img/sprite.png);
  background-position: -303px 0;
  width: 433px;
  height: 531px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 171px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="bill"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое